# total attribute in DisplayTag

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

Below is my jsp , when I add total attribute to display:column I get below exception

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException in '/jsp/frm_Rslt.jsp': /jsp/frm_Rslt.jsp(5,2) The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

frm_Rslt.jsp

```
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:display="urn:jsptld:http://displaytag.sf.net">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>


<%AppUtil oAppUtil=new AppUtil();%>
<jsp:useBean id="realTimeIssuance" scope="session" class="com.actionform.afRealTimeIssuance"></jsp:useBean>


<display:table name="realtimereportcol" export="true" pagesize="25" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator">
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename">RealTimeIssuance_<%=oAppUtil.getSystemDateTime()%>.xls</display:setProperty>

        <display:column title="SUB_CHANNEL" sortable="true" property="sub_channel" group="1"></display:column>
        <display:column title="AGENT_NAMES" sortable="true" property="agent_names"></display:column>
        <display:column title="FTD" sortable="true" property="ftd" total="true"></display:column>
        <display:column title="MTD" sortable="true" property="mtd" total="true"></display:column>
        <display:column title="QTD" sortable="true" property="qtd" total="true"></display:column>


</display:table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tlddoc/display/column.html) of the `<display:column>` tag, you will find the following description for the `total` attribute:

> **total:** If true, will total the contents of this column. This value is available via the Map named in varTotals for the table. ***Column values need to be Numbers***.

So please check if the columns `FTD`, `MTD` and `QTD` are numbers.